# How to setup periodic backups

Tags: django, django-apps, django-chronograph

I have a Django project which has a lot of apps. To backup the database, I am using django-dbbackup.

To backup the database, I use this: "python manage.py dbbackup" - This command basically does a backup of the existing database and stores it in a specified location.
What i want to do is, I want to execute this command periodically, using something like a  django-chronograph.

I would like to make an app which would schedule periodic execution of "dbbackup" command from django-dbbackup.
 How do I make it execute a specific command from another application (which is django-dbbackup).
A simple command line command would be fine.
Example, I create an app called BS,
It should work like this: "python manage.py bs" and then it should automatically execute the command from django-dbbackup and set up a cron job as well. How do I accomplish this? I have made an app called BS using "python manage.py startapp BS", and also added it in INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: These tasks are usually made by Cron jobs http://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job

Comment: Why do you want an intermediary app that would run the dbbackup command? You can just use a cronjob to run the `python manage.py dbbackup` without needing an extra app.

Comment: @AdrianGhiuta I need an intermediary app because I plan on adding some more functionality related to backups, and I would like to know how to make an intermediary app! Editing dbbackup app is not an option right now.